# How do I display images from back office in windows phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building my first app in windows phone 7. I need to show some data from web service along with an image. I am able to show the data but do not know how to display the images. New data can be entered which needs to be updated. The image will come from backoffice and the path will come from web service. My web service is:

```
 <string><NewDataSet>
  <UserDetails>
    <id>5</id>
    <News_Title>Audit of Electricity Companies</News_Title>
    <News_Description> Rejecting the contention of private power distributors, the Delhi government today ordered an audit of their finances by the government's national auditor or Comptroller and Auditor General (CAG), fulfilling yet another election promise of the Aam Aadmi Party.

</News_Description>
    <Date_Start>2014-01-03</Date_Start>
    <image_path>news.png</image_path>
  </UserDetails>
```

There will be more than 1 data. I am able to show news_Title, news_description, Date_start. My cs code is

```
 public class Newss
    {
        public string News_Title { get; set; }
        public string News_Description { get; set; }
        public string Date_Start { get; set; }
    }




    public News()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KejriwalService.aapSoapClient client = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
        client.getarvindNewsCompleted += new EventHandler<KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs>(client_getarvindNewsCompleted);
        client.getarvindNewsAsync();
    }

    void client_getarvindNewsCompleted(object sender, KejriwalService.getarvindNewsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string result = e.Result.ToString();
        List<Newss> listData = new List<Newss>();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
        // Just as an example of using the namespace...
        //var b = doc.Element("NewDataSet").Value;
        foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
        {
            Newss data = new Newss();
            data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;

           // data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
            data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
            listData.Add(data);
        }
        listBox1.ItemsSource = listData;

    }
```

My xaml file is

```
 <ScrollViewer Margin="12,17,-12,144" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
            <ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="38,86,38,562">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}"></TextBlock>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model

```
public class Newss
{
    public string News_Title { get; set; }
    public string News_Description { get; set; }
    public string Date_Start { get; set; }
    public string Image_Path { get; set; }
}
```

Set the image property in your foreach loop

```
foreach (var location in doc.Descendants("UserDetails"))
    {
        Newss data = new Newss();
        data.News_Title = location.Element("News_Title").Value;

       // data.News_Description = location.Element("News_Description").Value;
        data.Date_Start = location.Element("Date_Start").Value;
        Newss.Image_Path  = location.Element("image_path").Value
        listData.Add(data);
    }
```

In your Xaml

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="12,17,-12,144" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AllowDrop="False" ManipulationMode="Control">
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="38,86,38,562">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=News_Description}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date_Start}"></TextBlock>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image_Path}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

And obviously, ensure that the Image_Path data from your xml payload is a valid uri, i would start by setting it to a static image such as "http://static.bbci.co.uk/frameworks/barlesque/2.59.4/orb/4/img/bbc-blocks-dark.png"

Comment: Control moves to the following line in app.xaml.cs when i run the application after adding the code you gave   // Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: Expand the exception object (e) - What does the Message and Inner exception say?

Comment: Can u please elaborate. I dint understand and i am new to this domain

Comment: Moreover i have an error in this line    Newss.Image_Path  = location.Element("image_path").Value             So i changed newss to data then only the program runs

Comment: It looks like image_path does not exist on your XML, your question xml data states "image_path". Should this be "Image_Path" as this is case sensitive. in any case, try  Newss.Image_Path = location.Element("image_path") == null ? "NoImage.jpg" : location.Element("image_path").Value;